# Lightswitch 2012 SQL server login error

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2012, authentication, visual-studio-lightswitch

**Environment**
Windows 7 machine running VS2012 Update 2
Server 2008 box running SQL Express 2012

Happily modifying existing Lightswitch application that connects to the SQL Server Express system using SQL Authentication. All of a sudden I start to get all sorts of funny errors (something weird happened at this point) so I stopped what I'm doing and restart both server and Win7 system.

When I now try to run/build my LS application it gets an error stating that login to the SQL Server failed because login is from an untrusted domain and windows authentication failed.

Problem is I am using SQL authentication???  I have triple checked my web.config settings and the connection string is definitely set for SQL auth.  I created another "test" application, again using SQL auth and it works fine. (I compared the config files from app to app and the connection strings are identical.

In the VS IDE I have Data Connections defined to the SQL server using SQL auth and it works fine. If I do an "update" of the data source and check connection dialog it uses SQL auth and the update works fine.

But when I try to build/run the app it wants to use Windows Authentication.

(I am not using any application/screen level security in my app).

Got me stumped.

Any ideas?